# How to receive this type of data in javascript from php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

in json code, original form is

```
                data: [
                  { x: 62, y: -78 },
                  { x: -0, y: 74 },

                ]
```

and I want to receive coordinate values from php values.
So I will make json code like

```
                data: [fromphpvalue]
```

Then how can I make that type of data from php?
I tried

```
$fromphpvalue = json_encode(array('x' => 62, 'y' =>-78), array('x' => 0, 'y' =>74));
echo "<script>var fromphpvalue= '$fromphpvalue';</script>";
```

But it doesn't worked.

Comment: you were close  but json_encode need to have one parameter for the data, so make it one array with 2 arrays inside `array(array(...),array(...))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your value on the first parameter of `json_encode`.

```
$fromphpvalue = json_encode([['x' => 62, 'y' => -78], ['x' => 0, 'y' => 74]]);
echo "<script>var fromphpvalue = $fromphpvalue;</script>";
```

Comment: Thank you!! And after I edited in javascript data: fromphpvalue, it worked!